# How to intepret or analyze the Augeas error for domain.xml of Jboss EAP

Tags: jboss, puppet, jboss-eap-6, augeas

I have tried to add a new attribute in the extensions element in domain.xml ( Jboss EAP ).

```
<domain xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.4">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.modcluster"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>
</domain>
```

Below are my commands what I have tried with. Please let me know whether I have done anything wrong.

```
set /augeas/load/xml/lens "Xml.lns" 
set /augeas/load/xml/incl "/opt/domain.xml"
load
set /files/opt/domain.xml/domain/extensions/#attribute/name = "arunraj"
save
```

I am getting the following error. Please guide me how to analyze or degug it.

> /augeas/files/opt/PuppetRepo/domain.xml/error/message = "Failed to
>   match \n    { /#attribute/ }?({ /#text/ =
>   /(\\]\\]\\]*[^]\001-\004<>][^]\001-\004<]*\\]|(\\][^]\001-\004<]|[^]\001-\004<][^]\001-\004<])[^]\001-\004<]*\\]|[^]\001-\004<]\\])(\\]\\]*[^]\001-\004<>][^]\001-\004<]*\\]|[^]\001-\004<][^]\001-\004<]*\\])*(\\]\\]*([^]\001-\004<>][^]\001-\004<]*|)|[^]\001-\004<][^]\001-\004<]*|)|\\]\\]\\]*([^]\001-\004<>][^]\001-\004<]*|)|(\\][^]\001-\004<]|[^]\001-\004<][^]\001-\004<])[^]\001-\004<]*|\\]|[^]\001-\004<]/
>   } | { /#comment/ = /([^\001-\004-]|-[^\001-\004-])*/ } | <> |
>   { /[:A-Z_a-z][.0-:A-Z_a-z-]*/ = /#empty/ } | { /#pi/ })*\n  with
>   tree\n    { \"#text\" = \"\n        \" } { \"extension\" = \"#empty\"
>   } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } { \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } {
>   \"#text\" = \"        \" } { \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\"
>   = \"        \" } { \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } { \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"        \" } {
>   \"extension\" = \"#empty\" } { \"#text\" = \"    \" } { \"#attribute\"
>   }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#attribute` node you are trying to add must come before the `extension` nodes. You need to use `insert` for that:

```
augtool> ins #attribute before /files/tmp/domain.xml/domain/extensions/*[1]
augtool> set /files/tmp/domain.xml/domain/extensions/#attribute[1]/name "arunraj"
```

Comment: @Raphink : Thanks for the answer.